# JavaScript, using a function to change the text displayed in a HTML <p> tag

Tags: javascript, while-loop, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have a HTML5 canvas, which is displaying a number of images and a paragraph of text on the page underneath the canvas. I want the text in the paragraph to be updated to display a different element from a JS array depending on which image the user clicks on.

Currently, I have a 'mousedown' function that looks like this:

```
    _mousedown: function(evt) {
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
    if(obj && obj.shape) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        this.clickStart = true;
        shape._handleEvent('mousedown', evt);
        isClickOnImage(evt);
        var id = shape.id;
        selectTip(id);
    }

    //init stage drag and drop
    if(Kinetic.DD && this.attrs.draggable) {
        this._initDrag();
    }
}
```

I tried using the line `var id = shape.id` to update the ID that's being passed to the function, so that it will get the correct element from my 'tips' array, but for some reason, when I view the page in the browser, and click on an image, the text beneath the canvas is not updated. It seems that this function is not updating the 'id' variable to the ID of whichever image has been clicked.

After looking into this, it seems to me that I will want to use a loop inside the 'mousedown' function, that will take the 'id' of the image on which the click has been detected, and loop through my 'sources' array (which is where all of the images have been loaded from the HTML into the JS), checking at each position whether the image stored at that location has the same ID as that of the image that has been clicked on. If it does, the loop should set the text to the text stored at that position of the array, and if not, it should continue looking through the array until it find it. Would this make sense? I tried adding the following code to the 'mousedown' function, but it doesn't change the text as I expected:

```
var imageCheckArray = 0;
        while(imageCheckArray < sources.length){
            if(shape.id == sources[imageCheckArray]){
                selectTip(imageCheckArray);
            } else {
                imageCheckArray++;
            }
        }
```

Is there something I'm missing from the loop?

The code for the whole function currently looks like this:

```
_mousedown: function(evt) {
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
    if(obj && obj.shape) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        this.clickStart = true;
        shape._handleEvent('mousedown', evt);
        isClickOnImage(evt);
        /*This line needs to get the element of the sources array that has been selected, 
            and then select the element at the same position from the tips array.*/
        //var id = null;
        var imageCheckArray = 0;
        while(imageCheckArray < sources.length){
            if(shape.id == sources[imageCheckArray]){
                selectTip(imageCheckArray);
            } else {
                imageCheckArray++;
            }
        }

        //var id = 
        //selectTip(id);
    }

    //init stage drag and drop
    if(Kinetic.DD && this.attrs.draggable) {
        this._initDrag();
    }
}
```

**Edit 11/01/2013 @ 16:10**

The code for `selectTip` is:

```
function selectTip(id){
    $("#tipsParagraph").text(tips[id]);
}
```

and I've put a jsFiddle up here: http://jsfiddle.net/cd8G7/ although the 'result' panel is not showing what I actually see when I view the page in my browser- I get the canvas with all of the images displayed, and the paragraph underneath the canvas shows the text from the first element of my 'tips' array.

**Edit 23/01/2013 @ 13:50**

Here's my `isClickOnImage` function:

```
function isClickOnImage(event){
    var clickX = event.clientX;
    var clickY = event.clientY;

    //var imageCheckIteration = 0;
    while(imageCheckIteration < sources.length){
        if((clickX > sources[imageCheckIteration].x && clickX < sources[imageCheckIteration].x + imageWidth) &&
        (clickY > sources[imageCheckIteration].y && clickY < sources[imageCheckIteration].y + imageHeight)){
            /*This is where I need to print the variable that holds the text I want to display, but I need to display its contents
            outside the canvas, in the <p></p> tags below. */
            console.log("Click on image detected");
            document.getElementById("tipsParagraph").innerHTML = sources[imageCheckIteration].data-tip /*tips[imageCheckIteration]*/;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("tipsParagraph").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
}
```

What I intended that this function do is, capture the X & Y coordinates of any click on the canvas, and store them in the variables "clickX" and "clickY". Then, I have a variable called "imageCheckIteration" that has been initialised to 0, and while this variable is less than the length of my "sources" array (which is the array where all of the images have been stored), the function should check whether the click was on an area of the canvas that is covered by one of the images in the array.

If it was, then a console log should display the message "click on image detected", and the line

```
document.getElementById("tipsParagraph").innerHTML = sources[imageCheckIteration].data-tip;
```

should set the value of the "tipsParagraph" to be the value of the 'data-tip' attribute of whichever image is at the 'imageCheckIteration' position of the 'sources' array. If the click was detected on an area of the canvas that does not have an image displayed, then the value of the "tipsParagraph" should be set to hold nothing.

However, for some reason, when I view the page in the browser, the 'tipsParagraph' displays the text "This is where the text will be displayed", which is its default value, so that's fine. But, when I click on an image, or click anywhere else on the canvas, the text displayed  in the 'tipsParagraph' is not updated.

I can't figure out why this is- can someone point me in the right direction? Does it mean that my `isClickOnImage(event)` function is never being called?

Comment: Could you include the code for `selectTip`? Maybe a jsFiddle which replicates the issue? Right now, it's difficult to see where the problem lies. For starters, try `console.log(id)` in your `mousedown` function before you call `selectTip` and see what the value is.

Comment: I added the `console.log(id)` just before the call to `selectTip`, but when viewing the page in the browser, the log never appeared in the console, which I guess means that this code isn't being called at all? I'll add the code for `selectTip` and link to a jsFiddle now.

Comment: the JavaScript field needs tidying up a little remove the html script tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the way you are getting a reference to an image through the canvas. The trick here is to swap the z-index of the canvas and the image container and grab the reference to the image on the mouse up event. I don't know of a clean way to get elements behind a canvas, hence the workaround.

```
$('canvas').bind('mousedown', function(e) {
  $('section').css('z-index', 4);
});

$('img').bind('mouseup', function(e) {
  $('#tipsParagraph').text($(this).attr('id') + ":" + $(this).attr('alt'));
  $('section').css('z-index', 2);
});
```

The second portion here is grabbing some attributes from the image itself and updating the text inside your div.

You can see more of the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cd8G7/8/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've tried making the adjustments you suggested- I've added in the parts of the CSS that I didn't have, and have put the JS from the fiddle in at the end of the script in the <head></head> section of my page, but for some reason, I still just have the first element from the 'tips' array being displayed underneath the canvas straight away when the page loads (i.e. before any user interaction). When I do click on an image, this text is not updated. I see that in the fiddle you've written, you are using the image 'alt' tags to store the text that you want to display...

Comment: I can't do this, as I am using the 'alt' tags to say which group each image belongs to. (Later, I will want the user to drag each image to a 'description area', and the image should disappear from the canvas when dragged to the correct one. I am using the 'alt' tag to state which description area each image belongs to.) So, I am using an array, called 'tips' to store the text that I want to display. Each element in the 'tips' array corresponds to the image at the same position in the 'images' array, so what I want to do is: depending on the position of the selected image in the images array,

Comment: the elements of the tips array that is at the same position should be displayed in the <p> tags outside the canvas. Does this make sense? Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: you can add data attributes to the img tag to hold the data you want. No need for arrays. For instance you could use data-tip to store the tip and data-group to store the group. http://jsfiddle.net/cd8G7/11/

Comment: When I add the "data-tip" and "data-group" attributes into my <img> tags, the types "data-tip" and "data-group" are highlighted in red by my text editor- I don't know if this is because it has determined that there is some error with what I've done? The line I now  have is: `<img id="building" src="images/assets/building.png" alt="Asset" data-group="asset" data-tip="Building: A building is a physical item, owned by the company, that can be bought or sold for cash" />` Is this correct?

Comment: If I am right with how I've added the attributes you suggested above, presumably, I need to add code to the function I have that's checking if a click is on an image to set the 'innerHTML' of my <p> tag to the 'data-tip' element of whichever image of my array is selected?

Comment: I tried adding the "data-tip" and "data-group" attributes to one of the <img> tags in my HTML, and also added code to my while loop, which was checking the position of the mouse click against the positions of all of the images in the array, to see if the click was on any of the images, but nothing happens when a click on an image is detected... any ideas why? I'll add the code for my `isClickOnImage` function now.